# Add value to first or last of a String.ValueOf(int) depending on int value

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Like the title , I'm trying to add char Sequences to a String depending on my int values,
EX : range from 1 -> 10000, bar = 22 so output must be 00022
What've tried and worked:

```
if (bar < 10)
 String foo = "0000" + String.valueOf(bar);
if (bar < 100 && bar >= 10)
 String foo = "000" + String.valueOf(bar);
if (bar < 1000 && bar >= 100)
 String foo = "00" + String.valueOf(bar);
if (bar >= 1000)
 String foo = "0" + String.valueOf(bar);
```

Is there any way to do this more simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String foo = String.format("%05d", bar);
```

That will add the correct amount of 0's to the beginning of the string.

Comment: It can be `"%05d".formatted(bar)` in Java 15+.